# How to access fields of a value bound to a variable in a match expression?

Tags: binding, pattern-matching, rust, variant

I have code similar to:

```
use std::string::{String};
use std::vec::{Vec};

enum State {
    A {
        n: usize,
        lines: Vec<String>,
    },
    B {
        n: usize,
    }
}

fn main() {
    use State::*;

    let lines = vec!["a", "b", "GO", "c", "GO", "d"];
    let mut state = B { n: 0 };
    for line in &lines {
        state = match state {
            A { n, lines } => {
                if line == &"GO" {
                    B { n: n + 1 }
                } else {
                    let mut new_lines = Vec::from(lines);
                    new_lines.push(line.to_string());
                    A { n: n, lines: new_lines }
                }
            },
            B { n } => {
                A { n: n, lines: vec![line.to_string()] }
            },
        };
    }
    let final_n = match state {
        A { n, .. } => n,
        B { n } => n,
    };
    println!("final_n = {}", final_n);
}
```

Rust Playground link:  http://is.gd/0QTYaQ

(Note that this is a simplification of the actual code.  See the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33588734/1) of this question for the full background.)

I want to avoid creating the `new_lines` vector, so I tried binding the `State::A` value to a variable and accessing the fields of the value like so:

```
            s @ A { .. } => {
                if line == &"GO" {
                    B { n: s.n + 1 }
                } else {
                    s.lines.push(line.to_string());
                    s
                }
            },
```

However, this fails to compile:

```
ParseState_enum_test.rs:23:28: 23:31 error: attempted access of field `n` on type `State`, but no field with that name was found
ParseState_enum_test.rs:23                     B { n: s.n + 1 }
                                                      ^~~
ParseState_enum_test.rs:19:5: 33:6 note: in this expansion of for loop expansion
ParseState_enum_test.rs:25:21: 25:28 error: attempted access of field `lines` on type `State`, but no field with that name was found
ParseState_enum_test.rs:25                     s.lines.push(line.to_string());
                                               ^~~~~~~
ParseState_enum_test.rs:19:5: 33:6 note: in this expansion of for loop expansion
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

How do I access the fields of the value bound to the variable?

**EDIT:** I am aware of `ref mut` in pattern binding, but I don't think that this is a good solution in my case.  If I use `ref mut`, then I need to create a clone of the vector because this code does not compile:

```
            A { n, ref mut lines } => {
                if line == &"GO" {
                    B { n: n + 1 }
                } else {
                    lines.push(line.to_string());
                    A {
                        n: n,
                        lines: lines, // error: mismatched types
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: I **guarantee** you can [make a smaller example](http://is.gd/363IR1) :-) This is called an [MCVE](/help/mcve) and is a *very* good idea when asking a question on Stack Overflow! Also note that having code that runs on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) is **strongly** preferred.

Comment: It's still very long compared to the question you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following seems to work. Does it solve the problem?

```
    let new_state = match state { 
        B {n} => A { n: n, lines: vec![line.to_string()] },
        A {n, mut lines} => {
            match *line {
                "GO" => B { n: n + 1 },
                _ => {
                    lines.push(line.to_string());
                    A{ n:n, lines: lines}
                }
            }
        }
    };
    state = new_state
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4fa712834999e45ccd4d&version=stable

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a much simpler version of your issue:

```
enum Foo {
    Alpha { score: u8 },
    Beta { lives_left: u8 },
}

fn main() {
    let the_value = Foo::Alpha { score: 42 };
    match the_value {
        alpha_only @ Alpha => println!("Score is {}", alpha_only.score),
        _ => println!("Dunno what to do!"),
    }
}
```

The problem is that enum variants are not standalone types. That is, there is *no way* to have a variable of type `Foo::Alpha`; you can only have it be the type `Foo`. You can see this in the error message:

> attempted access of field `score` **on type `Foo`**, but no field with that name was found

When you use `@` to bind the entire pattern, you can only know that you are getting something of type `Foo`.

The normal way of dealing with this is to bind to a component of the item using `ref`:

```
match the_value {
    Foo::Alpha { ref score } => println!("Score is {}", score),
    _ => println!("Dunno what to do!"),
}
```

And if you need to mutate the value, use `ref mut`:

```
match the_value {
    Foo::Alpha { ref mut score } => {
        *score += 1;
        println!("Score is {}", score)
    },
    _ => println!("Dunno what to do!"),
}
```

Of if you can consume the value, you don't need `ref`:

```
let the_value = Foo::Alpha { score: 42 };
let new_value = match the_value {
    Foo::Alpha { score } => Foo::Alpha { score: score + 1 },
    Foo::Beta { lives_left } => Foo::Alpha { score: lives_left * 2 },
};
```

Comment: This oversimplifies my question too much and thus does not answer it.  I was already aware of `ref mut` and how that is typically used.  The problem here is that I need to return the updated state containing the vector.  I can't just return a new `A` value with the `lines` mut ref because `A` needs the actual vector.  See the edit to my question.

Comment: @DanielTrebbien then your question seems to have nothing to do with pattern matching or binding. You want to "avoid creating the `new_lines` vector" and don't want to "create a clone of the vector", but you simply **cannot** change the data you are iterating on because the body of your loop *doesn't own it*. You may just want to change to `for line in lines` and consume the input vector?

Comment: I am not changing the data that I am iterating on, which I agree would be prohibited in Rust.  Here, a new value of `state` is created with each iteration of the loop and the previous `state` value is overwritten.  I can create mutable values for each of the variables held in state (e.g. http://is.gd/AMTPgi ); however, it's not very elegant.